# Data not being inserted in table

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I am using the code below that uploads a file and inserts data into the "Image" table using mysqli:

```
<?php
/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    die();
}

$result = 0;

//UPLOAD IMAGE FILE

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileImage"]["tmp_name"], "ImageFiles/" . $_FILES["fileImage"]["name"]);

$result = 1;

//INSERT INTO IMAGE DATABASE TABLE

$imagesql = "INSERT INTO Image (ImageFile) VALUES (?)";

if (!$insert = $mysqli->prepare($imagesql)) {
    // Handle errors with prepare operation here
}

//Dont pass data directly to bind_param store it in a variable
$insert->bind_param("s", $img);

//Assign the variable
$img = 'ImageFiles/' . $_FILES['fileImage']['name'];

$insert->execute();

$insertimagequestion->execute();

//IF ANY ERROR WHILE INSERTING DATA INTO EITHER OF THE TABLES
if ($insert->errno) {
  // Handle query error here
}

$insert->close();


$lastID = $mysqli->insert_id;

 $imagequestionsql = "INSERT INTO Image_Question (ImageId, SessionId, QuestionId) 
    VALUES (?, ?, ?)";


    if (!$insertimagequestion = $mysqli->prepare($imagequestionsql)) {
      // Handle errors with prepare operation here
       echo "Prepare statement err";
    }

$sessid =  $_SESSION['id'] . ($_SESSION['initial_count'] > 1 ? $_SESSION['sessionCount'] : '');

$insertimagequestion->bind_param("isi",$lastID, $sessid, $_POST['numQuestion'][$i]);

        $insertimagequestion->execute();

                if ($insertimagequestion->errno) {
          // Handle query error here
        }

        $insertimagequestion->close();

}
?>
```

So for example if I insert 2 images "cat.png" and "dog.png" into "Image" Database table, it will insert it like this:

```
  ImageId         ImageFile

    220             cat.png
    221             dog.png

(ImageId is an auto increment)
```

Anyway what I want to do is that when a file is uploaded, not only is the data inserted into the table above, but I want to also be able to retrieve the ImageId that was inserted above and place it in the "Image_Question" table below so it would be like this:

```
ImageId         SessionId      QuestionId

    220            AAA             1 
    221            AAB             4
```

But it is not inserting anything in the Image_Question table. How when I upload an image, it not only inserts data into the "Image" table but be able to insert the data into the "Image_Question" table as well?

Comment: Do you not get an error?  It seems like `$insert->close()` is probably invalid.

Comment: I don't have any errors from the php error report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgive me if I'm way off, but doesn't the php execute sequentially, in other words,
Shouldn't this: `$insertimagequestion->execute();`
go after this: `if (!$insertimagequestion = $mysqli->prepare($imagequestionsql))`
?
Perhaps the first occurrence of `$insertimagequestion->execute();` is wiping out the insert id.  I'd put in something to print & make sure you're getting the insert_id.

Comment: Can you show me how you would layout the code because I tried putting the execute after the prepare statement but still no change. But if I can see how you would lay it out then I will follow it and see what happens.

Comment: i would comment out the first instance of `$insertimagequestion->execute();`  where it appears after `$insert->execute();`  then i would add `print $lastID` on the line after `$lastID = $mysqli->insert_id;` and make sure you're getting the insert id.

Comment: The problem is though is that this script is performed on the background, so I won't be able to see any print anyway.

Comment: if you're running it from the web, you can change the "print" to "print STDERR" and the messages should show up in the web error logs.